# Warning Error: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the....?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd, use-effect, use-state

I', new to react and I was using a custom component for multiple date picker for my main application but as soon as I use my component for multiple date picker it gives me an error like:

> State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support
> the " + 'second callback argument. To execute a side effect after ' +
> 'rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

Kinda confuse with the error. I'm attaching the relevant code with it.

**Multi date piker component**

```
import React, { useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { Select, Calendar, Tag } from "antd";

function toValidArray(value) {
    const arr = Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value];

    return arr.filter(e => e != null && e != undefined); // must be ==
}

const MultipleDatePicker = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const { onChange = () => { }, format = "DD/MM" } = props;

    const { value } = props;




    // console.log(onChange);

    console.log('multiDatePicker value', value)

    const arrValues = useMemo(() => toValidArray(value), [value]);

    const customRenderDate = useCallback(
        current => {
            if (arrValues.some(e => current.isSame(e))) {
                return <div className={"selectedDate"}>{current.format("DD")}</div>;
            }

            return <div>{current.format("DD")}</div>;
        },
        [arrValues]
    );

    const renderTag = useCallback(
        ({ value, onClose }) => {
            return (
                <Tag onClose={onClose} closable>
                    {value?.format(format)}
                </Tag>
            );
        },
        [format]
    );

    const _onChange = useCallback(
        selected => {
            const index = arrValues.findIndex(e => e.isSame(selected));
            const temp = [...arrValues];

            if (index !== -1) {
                temp.splice(index, 1);
            } else {
                temp.push(selected);
            }

            onChange(temp);
        },
        [arrValues, onChange]
    );

    const onDeselect = useCallback(
        oldSelect => {
            const newVal = arrValues.filter(e => !e.isSame(oldSelect));
            onChange(newVal);
        },
        [arrValues, onChange]
    );

    return (
        <Select

            className="select"
            mode="tags"
            size={'large'}
            value={arrValues}
            dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}
            onDeselect={onDeselect}
            tagRender={renderTag}
            dropdownRender={() => {
                return (
                    <div className={"calendar"}>
                        <Calendar

                            fullscreen={false}
                            dateFullCellRender={customRenderDate}
                            onSelect={_onChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                );
            }}
        />
    );
});

MultipleDatePicker.propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    value: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.array,
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.object
    ]),
    format: PropTypes.string
};

export default MultipleDatePicker;
```

****The main component using the Multi date picker****

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';


function CalendarNew() {
  const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);

return (

       <div className='multiple-date-picker'>
           <MultipleDatePicker value={dates} onChange={setDates} />
       </div>
)
}
```

**Error message**

[image]

**full error message**
[image]

Comment: I don't think you've shown us the code generating the error. None of your code makes the particular mistake this error refers to. Please paste the full error message (stack trace if there is one).

Comment: HI thanks for the reply, I added the question. Please let me know if anything is wrong.

Comment: Will be getting props from the main component like the changes in value and onChange.

Comment: What if you split this line? `const { onChange = () => { }, value, format = "DD/MM" } = props;`  One line to define your two constants OnChange and Format and another to destructure the value prop. Does that change the error message?

Comment: `const { onChange = () => { }, format = "DD/MM" } = props;`
`const { value } = props;`
if you mean like this then it's not changing the error.

Comment: Before the exception was line 14. After this change which of these two new lines has the error?

Comment: ok, I just check it the error is coming when I console.log(onChange).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239517/discussion-between-nlta-and-sharanjeet-singh).